# iOS FacebookSDK - New Developer Alert for App - v2.6 Upgrade Reminder

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an app that uses some limited functionality from the FacebookSDK. I got two alerts from Facebook seeing that my app is using calls from API version 2.6 . I checked the app and found where I explicitly specify the API version and updated it. However, I've received another email and see that the app is making outdated API calls here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/

It seems that these calls are coming from FBSDKCoreKit.

**How do I properly upgrade an iOS app to resolve the New Developer Alert for App -  v2.6 Upgrade Reminder?**

- OR -

**Should I disregard this reminder, as old calls can be coming from older versions of the app which have not updated their app?** (So would some calls always be made against the old API?)

[image]

I checked, and I'm using the latest pods, and have explicitly upgraded the API version string:

```
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.31.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.31.1)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.31.1)

// Here's one of the requests:
 let graphRequest =  FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me/friends",
                                            parameters: params,
                                            tokenString: tokenString,
                                            version: "v2.11",
                                            httpMethod: "GET")
```

Comment: _“(So would some calls always be made against the old API?)”_ - nope, API calls against retired API versions are simply silently upgraded to the next available version automatically.

Comment: _“However, I've received another email and see that the app is making outdated API”_ - while you may have updated your app’s code, that must not necessarily mean every user already has updated their installed version as well (assuming you are talking about an active app with an actual user base here, and not just a private test app or sth. like that) … so that you would still be getting those notifications for a while might be rather natural.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to explicitly update the API version in:

Facebook App > Settings > Advanced:

[image: facebook api upgrade option]